# Google API service account in Angular app

Tags: angularjs, node.js, oauth, google-api, single-page-application

This sounds like a popular scenario, but I can't find direct answer nowhere...

I want to plot Analytics data in my app's admin area.
This area is used by multiple users of the company, and they have to authenticate to access this area. I plan to use GA service account, but 'browser-key/domain' option seems only available for public api.

Can I use server auth (through node API), get the token, and pass it to user while logging in? Will the token be valid? Can I have multiple valid tokens simultaneously for all the users?

Or maybe there is some other way to do it?

Comment: Currently the api Nodejs client API is in Alpa. It will probably be buggy, but you could use that. [Source](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/gdataLibraries) Otherwise you will need to use a different language for your backend.

Comment: Why do I need api? I want need token on server side, for passing to client(s) side... https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount#makingrequest

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were wanting to use the api to return data from google analytics and display it. What do you want to do?

Comment: I want do display it in Angular single-page app

Comment: In which case you would need to use the api on the server to return the data and then display it in your SPA.

Comment: @sonia - Can you tell me how to form **grant_type** and **assertion** to call the rest API

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I've tested it myself and the answer is:

YES, you get universal (max 60min) token with every request - so you can have many of them, and dispose to you client-side apps as needed.

I have now embedApi widget in my Angular.js dashboard for every user, without login.

Comment: Can you share how you achieve this?